# Codeigniter redirect to a public_html folder

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to place all my static assets (js, css, etc) in a separate folder "public_html". But of course I still want my url to be: http://www.domain.com instead of http://domain.com/public_html

This can be done with .htaccess I suppose but haven't had any luck with it.

Also do I configure my base_url in codeigniter to be http://www.domain.com or http://www.domain.com/public_html

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any luck on this, i'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public_html is the folder on your server where you put your codeigniter files into. In your config file you set the base_url as be http://www.domain.com.

You can put the assets folder in the public_html folder and the url will still be http://www.domain.com.

Example file structure.

```
server
- www
- etc
- public_html
  - application
    - config
      - config.php
  - system
  - assets
    - css
    - images
    - js
```

Comment: Maybe I'm getting you wrong but I want all my codeigniter files in the root, and then a folder "public_html" in the root which only contains js, css, etc. If I do this, and I set my base_url to domain.com (without '/public_html') I get a 404.

Comment: That is because you need to put ALL your files in the public_html folder. The public_html folder is for files that are to be used/viewed by someone over http I'm pretty sure.

Comment: I know every server has its public_html folder, and I know I have to put all my files in there. But I actually want another folder in there that just contains my static files. But I don't want my base_url to be "domain.com/assets".

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example. If that doesn't work, try deleting everything out of your .htaccess file that is in your ROOT directory (not the one in the public_html directory if there is one).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have always put my base_url to point to my assets folder (and then trying to remove that from the url with .htaccess). I'm now pointing to the root and fixed my css and js links (added "assets/" in front of it). I guess this is the best approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm pretty sure it's a better pratice to have your system and application directory out of the public_html folder. Something like this:

```
- www
  - application
  - public_html
    - css
    - images
    - js
    - index.php
  - system
```

No codeigniter files but the index.php need to be in the public_html folder. You just have to point you index.php to them, adjusting 'system_path' and 'application_folder' in application/config/config.php.

In any event, it's safer for them not to be accessible externally.
It's also discussed in the codeigniter wiki: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Moving_your_app_out_of_DOCROOT/